# Good introduction to Morse-Novikov theory?

Tags: reference-request, books, morse-theory, differential-topology, dg.differential-geometry

Morse theory investigates the topology of compact manifolds using critical points of real-valued functions $f\colon\, M\to \mathbb{R}$. Motivated by problems in dynamical systems, Novikov ([Multivalued functions and functionals: An analogue of the Morse Theory](http://www.mi.ras.ru/~snovikov/68.pdf)) began to study Morse theory of closed $1$-forms, a special case of which is circle-valued Morse Theory (the subject of a very nice [book by Pajitnov](http://books.google.co.jp/books?id=WX7UWvjM1ogC&pg=PA335&lpg=PA335&dq=Pajitnov+Circle-valued+Morse+theory&source=bl&ots=JOCns1F6Dm&sig=ADnoRvzXo4rISY23V3IfUl5fh20&hl=ja&sa=X&ei=IspvT8rvJ8TsrAfnpN2gDg&ved=0CCMQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=Pajitnov%20Circle-valued%20Morse%20theory&f=false)). The key new idea was to use the Novikov ring, a certain ring of formal power series, as a tool to count gradient flow lines of an induced Morse function on a covering space of $M$.

Novikov's ideas have been quite influential, but I have not been able to find a good introductory text on general Morse-Novikov theory just by googling keywords. My interests are in classical differential topology, in low dimensions. The reason that I want such a reference is that I work quite a bit with finite covering spaces (not necessarily abelian covers), and I'm curious as to whether or not Morse-Novikov theory gives me a better intuitive handle on what is happening than just plain old garden-variety Morse theory.

> **Reference Request**: Can anyone recommend/ Does there exist a good introductory text on Morse-Novikov Theory?

Comment: Have you looked at "Topology of closed one-forms" by Farber (AMS, 2003)?

Comment: Didn't know about Farber's book- going to the library to look at it now.

Answer (score 3):

S. P. Novikov, *An analogue of Morse theory for many-valued functions. Certain properties of Poisson brackets.* Appendix I in Dubrovin, Novikov, and Fomenko, **Modern Geometry-Methods and Applications Part III. Introduction to Homology Theory.** This short paper was written for the student working through their textbook treatment of differential geometry.